# Automatically update selected option in the angular controller to a select within a nested repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select input that I want to update from within my model to be selected based on what I get from a REST API service.

I've created a simple [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mhedgpeth/3p5pq42j/5/) that illustrates my issue.

First it has a select with options inside of a nested ng-repeat, with the selection saved in the person object:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-bind="person.name"></td>
            <td>
                <select ng-options="color.name for color in person.availableColors" ng-model="person.favoriteColor"></select>
            </td>
            <td ng-bind="person.favoriteColor.name"></td>
        </tr>
```

In my model I initialize the `$scope` to be full of `people` each with a `favoriteColor`:

```
var red = new Color('red', true);
var orange = new Color('orange', false);
var pink = new Color('pink', false);
var blue = new Color('blue', true);

var michael = new Person('Michael', red, [red, orange, pink]);
var jack = new Person('Jack', orange, [orange, pink, blue]);
$scope.title = 'Favorite Colors';
$scope.people = [michael, jack];
```

When I bring up the page initially the correct `favoriteColor` option is shown in the select. However when I change the default, then press the Reset button, the view does not update as expected:

```
$scope.reset = function () {
    michael.favoriteColor = red;
    jack.favoriteColor = orange;
};
```

**My question:** How do I automatically propogate changes in the angular controller to a select within a nested repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ng-click='reset()'
```

instead of

```
ng-click='reset'
```

Comment: LOL. Looks like I need a little more work on reproducing my issue from my real site. Thanks for your help.